# Querying values jsonB in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table with ProductID (int) and ProductGroups jsonb.
The ProductGroups just have values in the json rather than tag names.  I want to be able to query the following data to get ProductID where ProductGroup contains 69.

```
ProductID   ProductGroups
125481      [134, 83]
128166      [134, 83]
128175      [134, 83]
128172      [134, 83]
131492      [69, 134]
131489      [69, 134]
131860      [128, 131, 133, 100, 71]
128142      [134, 83]
```

I have queried what I think of as normal jsonb with tag names in different tables with below query where I callout the name and value

```
SELECT * 
FROM trans."TxnHeader" mpt, jsonb_array_elements(mpt."ExtensionProperty") as ext 
where 1=1
and jsonb_typeof(mpt."ExtensionProperty") = 'array'
and ext->>'Name' = 'posTranId' and ext->>'Value' = '8539'
```

Comment: Please post data as text, not a link to a painting of it.

Comment: What is the problem, what does not work? What is your question?

Comment: ok, added my data inline in the question.  Trying to figure out how to code the where clause to grab a record where the value is 69

Basically Where ext->>'Value' = 69

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the containment operator `@>` as follows :

```
select *
from products
where ProductGroups @> '69'
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/lSN6zzZ1)

Comment: Glad to hear :) If you see it usefull can you accept it